# Pass object (that will go out of scope) by reference

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, reference, pass-by-reference, undefined-behavior

So I have this function:

```
addDataToList(..., QVariant metadata) { }
```

The relevant `QVariant` constructor in this case is: `QVariant(const QString & val)`.

Now I have a function `foo()`, from where I call `addDataToList()` function.
How do I pass a valid value to the `QVariant` object?

If I have something like this:

```
void foo() {
    QString str = "String";
    addDataToList(..., QVariant(str));
}
```

It will not work because `str` object will go out of scope, leading into undefined behavior.

But if I create the string on heap, something like this:

```
void foo() {
    QString *str = new QString("String");
    addDataToList(..., QVariant(*str));
}
```

It will work, but there will be some memory leaks (because `QVariant` doesn't take ownership of the passed pointer).

How do I solve this situation?

EDIT: This is the actual implementation of `addDataToList(...)`:

```
void TPMSvalidator::addDataToList(const QString &data, bool useMetadata, MessageTypes type, QVariant metadata) {
    QString text;
    QIcon okIcon(QDir::currentPath() + "\\Resources\\Icons\\ok3.png");
    QIcon notOkIcon(QDir::currentPath() + "\\Resources\\Icons\\notok.png");
    QIcon noticeIcon(QDir::currentPath() + "\\Resources\\Icons\\warning2.png");

    if (data != QString()) {
        QListWidgetItem *data_w = new QListWidgetItem;

        if (type == MessageTypes::notification) {
            data_w->setBackgroundColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::gray));
            data_w->setTextColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::black));
            data_w->setIcon(noticeIcon);
            text.append("NOTICE: ");
        }
        else if (type == MessageTypes::telegramOkInfo) {
            data_w->setBackgroundColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::gray));
            data_w->setTextColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::black));
            data_w->setIcon(okIcon);
            text.append("INFO: ");
        }
        else if (type == MessageTypes::telegramNotOkInfo) {
            data_w->setBackgroundColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::gray));
            data_w->setTextColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::red));
            data_w->setIcon(notOkIcon);
            text.append("INFO: ");
        }
        else if (type == MessageTypes::warning) {
            data_w->setBackgroundColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::darkYellow));
            data_w->setTextColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::black));
            text.append("WARNING: ");
        }
        else {
            data_w->setBackgroundColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::darkRed).light(130));
            data_w->setTextColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::white));
            data_w->setIcon(notOkIcon);
            text.append("ERROR: ");
        }

        text.append(data);
        data_w->setText(text);
        data_w->setFont(QFont("Helvetica"));

        if (useMetadata) {
            data_w->setData(Qt::UserRole, metadata);
        }

        ui.listData->addItem(data_w);

        if (ui.autoScrollCheckBox->isChecked()) {
            ui.listData->scrollToBottom();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are doing like that you need to handle memory cleaning by your own. You may use free.

Comment: QT examples suggest that the QVariant actually copies the passed value. Are you sure it doesn't? (namely `QVariant x, y(QString()), z(QString(""));` is in the examples). It shouldn't take a const-ref in this case, but then again QT doesn't update to the newest C++ that quickly.

Comment: `const &` parameters are generally to 1. promise not to change the value 2. keep from making a copy for the function call. It does not necesarily indicate that the reference will be kept.

Comment: `QVariant` only stores copies. (It would be pretty much useless otherwise.)

Comment: your interpretation of first scenario is wrong...pass by value copies the temp into function call stack ie addDataToList() will have it's own copy.so, it won't go out of scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
addDataToList(..., QVariant metadata) { }
```

You are taking a `QVariant` by value.  As such you will copy the the value passed to the function.  So in

```
addDataToList(..., QVariant(str));
```

You create a temporary `QVariant` and the contents of that temporary are copied into `metadata` in `addDataToList()`.  Now `metadata` is its own object and is not dependent on the temporary that you created.

Comment: Then why I randomly get `First-chance exception at 0x013D0497 (Qt5Guid.dll) in app.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00272FF4)`? (and the debugger points at the end brace of `addDataToList()` method).

If I use pointers and dynamically alocate memory the problem is gone!
(well, there are just some memory-leaks, of course, but no randomly crashes).

Comment: @MariusMarusanici What are you doing in `addDataToList()`?  If you were getting an exception why wouldn't you post that?

Comment: @MariusMarusanici: Stack overflow is usually caused by unbounded recursion. That is a different problem than dangling pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The first version with temporary object on the stack will work safely, because the temporary `QString` is copied by value into the `QVariant` - not only the reference.